# What does com.firebase.client.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP respong with?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to build off a chat application using Firebase on the web, and create and Android client.
In my web app, I send the Firebase Server's time stamp along with the message, but I seem to be having a bit of trouble on Android.
Using Firebase's Opensource chat app for Android, I have used the default Chat.java class, but when I try to send the time stamp using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` I get an error because I assume it would return an `int` but it returns a `Map`.

Right now I'm using a workaround and getting the time from the device itself, but I'm trying to keep it consistent and reduce room for error if people across time zones are going to be using the app.

Here's my current work around block

```
private void sendMessage() {
    EditText inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageInput);
    String input = inputText.getText().toString();
    Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    if (!input.equals("")) {
        // Create our 'model', a Chat object
        Chat chat = new Chat(name, input, timestamp, userID);
        // Create a new, auto-generated child of that chat location, and save our chat data there
        ref.push().setValue(chat);
        inputText.setText("");
    }
}
```

And Chat.java

public class Chat {

```
private String from;
private String text;
private int userID;
private Long timestamp;

// Required default constructor for Firebase object mapping
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Chat() { }

Chat(String from, String text, Long timestamp, int userID) {
    this.from = from;
    this.text = text;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public Long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public int getuserID() {
    return userID;
}
```

}

Comment: you need to set a field in firebase push Server.TIMESTAMP and than retrieve it if your client should know about the server time.

Comment: @lombausch like this: `ref.push().setValue(chat, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);`? That doesn't work for me but you might mean something else...

Comment: When you execute that code, what value do you see ending up for the new node in your Firebase dashboard?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Nothing actually shows up in the node when I execute that :(

Comment: The value set in Firebase and returned from the server will be an int. However, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is a Map. It must be sent to the server to be processed before it can be converted. You may want to try setting timestamp to null, and using a toJSON method that checks for null and replaces it with ServerValue.TIMESTAMP when calling push/set.

Answer (score 2):

It is too long to go into comment. I meant more something like this, which I used on number of occasions.

```
var chatUserRef = new Firebase("your url to chat user");
chatUserRef.child('time')
  .set(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
  .on('value', function(snapshot){
     var current_server_time = snapshot.val();
  });
```

It is in javascript nevertheless the principle should be the same in Java.

Comment: When I have done it before in JS, this works... Sorry about formatting

    
    `$('#chatInput').keypress(function (e) {

   var timestamp = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

   if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    
    var userName = userSnapshot.child(userID).child('name').val();
    
    var imgURL = userSnapshot.child(userID).child('img').val();

    var userInput = $('#chatInput').val();
    messagesRef.push({from:userName, userID:userID, text:userInput, timestamp:timestamp});
    $('#' + chatInputID).val('');
   }
  });`