# Get Firebase Timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know how can I get the value of the timeStamp from the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, directly from the HashMap? I know that when that value is sent to Firebase I get the long value, but I want to get that long before send it to Firebase.

Comment: May be this link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36659507/5916727

Comment: Since the final value for `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is determined on the Firebase servers, you cannot know the value before sending something to the server. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is typically easier to help if you describe what you are trying to accomplish, instead of starting from an assumed solution.

Comment: Im trying to add into a messagging app like a temporary item inside the adapter, because if the user tries to send and image it has to wait until its saved into the Firebase Database, so I add the temporary image and then when its saved by Firebase and pushed back into the app, I compare the timestamps and delete the temporary item of the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okie so after some research I found that we cannot use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` before sending it to database because

`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is set as a Map (containing {.sv: "timestamp"}) which tells Firebase to populate that field with the server's time. When that data is read back, it is the actual unix time stamp which is a Long.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744398/retrieve-servervalue-timestamp-from-firebase-in-android-app-when-data-is-sent)

By the way you can use android own timestamp and store it in Firebase.

```
            Calendar cc = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = cc.getTime();
            // SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
            SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
            timestamp = format2.format(date);
```

Comment: I don´t want to use the user cellphones timestamp, what I am using is the Firebase `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, but that gives me an object, from wich I need the long value of the timeStamp that has internally before send it to Firebase

Comment: I have added the info for it.

Comment: @andrea : for this you have to get from firebase database .you have to access from their using key.