# Cannot add timestamp in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have completed the Firebase Android Codelab here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/

When a message is sent, the name, photoUrl and text of the message have been grouped together like this:

[image]

I'm trying add a timestamp (ServerValue.TIMESTAMP) of that message in the group.

Code that's supposed to send message along with the name, photoUrl and text of the message + timestamp (originally from [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/friendlychat/MainActivity.java)):

```
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername,
                    mPhotoUrl, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP); //It's not supposed to be like this! What should I write instead?
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
            mMessageEditText.setText("");
            mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(MESSAGE_SENT_EVENT, null);
        }
    });
```

With the code above, I can't add a timestamp as I want to. Why? What should I do exactly?

[FriendlyMessage.java](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/friendlychat/FriendlyMessage.java):

```
    public class FriendlyMessage {

    private String id;
    private String text;
    private String name;
    private String photoUrl;
    private Long creationDate;

    public FriendlyMessage() {
    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl, Long creationDate) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public java.util.Map<String, String> getCreationDate() {
        return ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Long getCreationDateLong() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Long creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
}
```

See entire Firebase Android Codelab original project [here](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/android) (without timestamp).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816227/get-firebase-timestamp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500138/android-chat-crashes-on-datasnapshot-getvalue-for-timestamp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864974/how-to-use-the-firebase-server-timestamp-to-generate-date-created and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096128/when-making-a-pojo-in-firebase-can-you-use-servervalue-timestamp?lq=1 (there are probably more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this

```
public class FriendlyMessage {

    private String id;
    private String text;
    private String name;
    private String photoUrl;
    private Long creationDate;

    public FriendlyMessage() {
    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public java.util.Map<String, String> getCreationDate() {
        return ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Long getCreationDateLong() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Long creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

        result.put("id", id);
        result.put("text", text);
        result.put("name", name);
        result.put("photoUrl", photoUrl);
        return result;

    }

}
```

somewhere in your codes do this

```
Date someDate = new Date();

FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage("bla","bla","bla");

 String key = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push().getKey();
 Map<String, Object> postValues =  friendlyMessage.toMap();
 postValues.put("creationDate", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
 childUpdates.put("/"+MESSAGES_CHILD+"/" + key, postValues);
 Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

 mFirebaseDatabaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Comment: This is not what I want. Look at what I get with your code: http://imgur.com/NgaMoXc

Comment: I want a real creation date. Not '123' Can you fix your code? Thanks!

Comment: Hei Me123 you can get Timestamp by doing this someDate.getTime(), I updated the code FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage("bla","bla","bla",someDate.getTime());

Comment: But, this doesn't use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

Comment: I want the time at which the server receives the message.

Comment: Thanks, it's working! Now, how do I retrieve `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` back to the app?  I tried `System.out.println(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)` but it doesn't work...

Comment: System.out.println(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.get("creationDate"))

Answer (score 1):

You must change the datatype of your creationDate variable from Long to Map. Because `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` returns a Map value.

Here's how it should look:

```
public class FriendlyMessage {

    private String id;
    private String text;
    private String name;
    private String photoUrl;
    private Map creationDate;

    public FriendlyMessage() {
    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl, Map CreationDate) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public java.util.Map<String, String> getCreationDate() {
        return ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Map creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did test it and it works. Can you update the code in the question with the code you have after changing it to Map?

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. Can you please post your complete tested code?

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it out

Comment: Okay. But l, what about the part that actually pushes the message to the server? (`FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername,
                    mPhotoUrl, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: Nothing changes there

Comment: That's the problem! There should be changes there because it doesn't work: that's my question...

Comment: Please download the original project from the link in the question and test your suggestion. You'll see that it doesn't work

Comment: I did change the FriendlyMessage Constructor. Please replace your whole FriendlyMessage class with the one I provide on my answer

Comment: It's not working. I get many errors. Test your answer fully please (with Firebase server)

Comment: `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead` And then the app crashes.

Comment: Please test your suggestion with Firebase first.

Comment: I did test it and It's working just fine. Maybe you're doing something wrong.