# Number of users added in the last 7 days

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way possible to retrieve all users added within the last 7 days? When a user is added, a timestamp incl. date is added to their "information".

Like this for instance:
[image]

So the date formula is: D/M/YYYY. Can anyone help me understand how to do this?

PS: The weird `OL3geebfiGfn..... etc` is the users unique ID.

Comment: 'a timestamp inc. date'... A timestamp is a universal date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, store the "added" field in milliseconds using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718668/firebase-timestamp-to-date-and-time) to know more about how to do that easily.

So, now that you've stored the time in milliseconds, your "added" field would contain a `Long` value. So, you can now perform filtering on your queries to get the data that you need.

Check out [this part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) of the Firebase reference docs for the filtering methods - specially `startAt()` and `endAt()`.

For example, you want to retrieve the users added in the last 7 days - so 7 days in milliseconds is 86400000. You can simply run a query that is similar to the following to retrieve the users added during the period of "current time in milliseconds" to "current time in milliseconds - 86400000" :-

```
firebase.database().ref('posts').startAt(current time - 86400000).endAt(current time);
```

Comment: Well, I have added the timestamp you suggested to `added` and it is showing a number. I am trying to get the `currentTime` as you also wrote, but console logging the `currentTime` variable I have made for the firebase TIMESTAMP prints this: `{.sv: "timestamp"}` ??

Comment: And therefore I cannot compare the `added` value to the currentTime :(

Comment: I understand what you're saying. This happens because `TIMESTAMP` is saved as a map in the database. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25750727/7626492). Although its in java, you can still understand and apply the logic to javascript.

Comment: I figured it out thanks to you! Thank you very much kind sir!

Comment: Hahah I'm glad I could help!