# Using server timestamp for filtering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase provides a mechanism to insert [server timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-latency).

I was wondering if it also can be used for filtering. Like this:

```
var db = firebase.database();
var path = '/some/path';
var ref = db.ref(path);
ref.orderByChild('ts')
    .startAt(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
    .on('child_added', function(snap) {
        //do something
    });
```

> Error: Query: First argument passed to startAt(), endAt(), or
>   equalTo() cannot be an object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already set the 'ts' child of a bunch of entries, you would add an actual timestamp to your startAt method like `startAt('1473645571228')`.

You can create the Unix timestamp client side with Moment.js, or if you need it from Firebase, [you can quickly set and retrieve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304422/what-does-com-firebase-client-servervalue-timestamp-respong-with/25308684#25308684).

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're trying to use admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP directly as an argument to startAt, and Firebase does not allow using objects like ServerValue.TIMESTAMP directly in queries.

To achieve querying based on the current timestamp, you should use the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP when writing data. Here's an example of how you might use it:

```
const currentTimestamp = Date.now();
dataRef.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(currentTimestamp).once('value').then(snapshot => {
snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
  const key = childSnapshot.key;
  const data = childSnapshot.val();
  console.log(`Key: ${key}, Timestamp: ${data.timestamp}, Other Data: ${data.otherProperty}`);
})}).catch(error => {console.error('Error fetching data:', error)});
```